# Simulink: How to provide custom source

Tags: matlab, simulink

My question is how to provide to Simulink model an user-defined source (input). My project will simulate behavior of water reservoir with dams in case of flood. I need to define an input flood flow into the reservoir (e.g. a flow of  river) so I don't want any build-in function like "step" or "sine-wave" but my custom function which could look like this:

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkRgm.jpg)

So it's **time dependent**.

By which **simulink block** could I achieve it ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the data in your MATLAB workspace and use the [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block.

Comment: And how could I make it time-dependent ? I mean that the function depends of simulation time.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for the block, it's all explained in there. The data you supply is a function of time (e.g. a matrix with 2 columns, the first one being time, the second data).